# Mathematical comparison between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| ID | StartTime | EndTime |
+----+-----------+---------+
|  1 | 2:00pm    | 3:00pm  |
|  2 | 4:00pm    | 5:00pm  |
|  3 | 7:00pm    | 9:00pm  |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

I need to get the difference between the end time of one row and the start time of the NEXT row. i.e. End time of row 1 compared to start time of row 2, or end time of row 2 compared to start time of row 3.

Ideally I'd like a result that looks similar to

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | TimeDifference |
+----+----------------+
|  2 | 1.0 hours      |
|  3 | 2.0 hours      |
+----+----------------+
```

I have no clue whatsoever on how to do something like this. I'm thinking that I may need 2 temp tables, one to hold start times another for end times so that I can more easily do the comparisons, but honestly that's  just a shot in the dark at the moment.

FYI, on server 2008 in case that makes a difference for some of the commands.

Comment: Do a self join.

Comment: Are these actual time data types or is it the time stored as string?

Comment: Or... use analytic functions...

Comment: The time is stored as a datetime, I just trimmed it down to time for this example

Comment: LAG() or LEAD() analytic functions

Comment: Are you using End time from the preceding row to start time of the next row based off ID? And what version of sql server?

Comment: @scsimon, that's correct

Comment: If you're on 2012+ Gordon's answer will suffice, otherwise you will probably use a window function or self join.

Comment: On 2008, edited post to add that and some other clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since it's 2008 version you can't use the `Lead()` or `Lag()` window functions,  but you can use subqueries to mimic them:

```
SELECT Id, 
       DATEDIFF(minute,
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 EndTime
                FROM table t1
                WHERE t1.Id < t0.Id 
                ORDER BY t1.Id DESC
            ), StartTime) / 60.0 As TimeDifference 
FROM Table t0
WHERE EXISTS             
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM Table t2
    WHERE t2.Id < t0.Id    
)
```

Comment: I can't get this to run in SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I must have deleted the `(` in the last edit. fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE:  The question was not tagged SQL Server 2008 when this answer was written.

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(minute, lag(endtime) over (order by id), starttime) / 60.0 as hours_diff
from t;
```

This does not filter out any rows.  The description of the problem ("next row") and the sample data (which is based on "previous row") are inconsistent.

Comment: version is 2008, according to OP

Comment: Select should include only id and hours_diff

Comment: I'll give this an upvote since it appears to work if I had 2012+, but since I don't I can't accept it.

Comment: In production I'm going to go with this. We're upgrading our servers in a month so I'll hold off until then. This works perfectly in my test environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it

```
declare @t as table (ID int,  StartTime time , EndTime time)
INSERT @t SELECT 1  ,'2:00pm',     '3:00pm'  
INSERT @t SELECT 2  ,'4:00pm',     '5:00pm'  
INSERT @t SELECT 3  ,'7:00pm',     '9:00pm'


---- For sequential IDs
select 
a.ID
,a.StartTime
,a.EndTime
,datediff(minute, (SELECT EndTime FROM @t b where b.ID = a.ID - 1) , a.StartTime) / 60.0 as hours_diff
from @t a 


---- For non-sequential IDs

;WIth cte_times as (
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) as new_ID
    , ID
    ,StartTime
    ,EndTime
FROM 
    @t
) 
select 
a.ID
,a.StartTime
,a.EndTime
,datediff(minute, (SELECT EndTime FROM cte_times b where b.new_ID = a.new_ID - 1) , a.StartTime) / 60.0 as hours_diff
from cte_times a
```

Comment: That will work only if the ID values are consecutive. Any gap in the id numbers will break this query.

Comment: It's simple to resolve, is only necessary create a new unique id using row_number function. In some minutes I will post a new version

Comment: This gets me results very much like the lag. I like a lot.

Comment: Officially I'm going to use lag(), but that requires waiting a month or two for us to do an update. So in the meantime I'm going to accept this as the answer since it does work with 2008.